# Manipulating URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am new in JS, I am writing some extra filters on the Interface. So extra filter needs to add or update the parameter in the URL.

**Option 1. No parameter in existing URL:**

url = `https://custom.net/`

We want to add new parameter in the URL where **key** is`sector` and **value** is `IndependentConsultingDoctors`

Output will be: `https://custom.net/?sector=IndependentConsultingDoctors`

**Option 2. Update value in parameter of existing URL**

URL = `https://custom.net/?filter=title&sector=1234&sortby=1&page=1`

We want to update parameter in the URL where **key** is`sector` and **value** is `IndependentConsultingDoctors`

Output will be: URL = `https://custom.net/?filter=title&sortby=1&page=1&sector=IndependentConsultingDoctors`

**Option 3. Delete and add parameter:**

URL = `https://custom.net/?filter=title&reportype=1234&sortby=1&page=1`

We want to add new parameter in the URL where **key** is`sector` and **value** is `IndependentConsultingDoctors` and delete `reportype` and  `inspectiontype` parameters.

Output will be: URL = `https://custom.net/?filter=title&sortby=1&page=1&sector=IndependentConsultingDoctors`

The following is my code:

```
$(this).find('.btn').click(function(){  
    //var pathname = window.location.href;
    var pathname = "https://abc.com/?filter_by=title&filter_condition=&sector=1234&reportype=3455&sortby=1&page=1&itemperpage=10&input_list=&current_selected_option=2&masterfilter=%26itemperpage%3D10%26filter_by%3DAll%26filter_condition%3D%26sortby%3D1%26from_date%3D%26to_date%3D&from_date=&to_date="
    // Key and Value which need to add in paramaetrs  
    var key = "sector"
    var value = "Acutes";
    // Delete key from the parameters
    var delete_key = ["reportype", "inspectiontype"];

    // Split URL BASE and Get Parameters
    split_href = pathname.split("?");

    //No parameter present   
    if (split_href.length==1) {
         window.location.href = split_href[0]+'?'+key+'='+value;
    }else{
        // Create dictionary of parameter
        var para_dict = {};
        var para_list = split_href[1].split("&");
        for (ii in para_list){
            var tmp = para_list[ii].split("=");
            para_dict[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
        }
        // Add target kay and Value
        para_dict[key] = value;

        // Delete key from the dinctionary
        for (ii in delete_key){
            delete para_dict[delete_key[ii]];       
        }
        //Create New Parameter string
        var new_para = "?";
        for (ii in para_dict){
            new_para = new_para+ii+"="+para_dict[ii]+"&";   
        }
        console.log(split_href[0]+new_para);
    }

});
```

Can you review my code and give me a more optimized solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good, but a few typographical things I can see are:

---

### Whitespace:

> ```
> if (split_href.length==1) {
> window.location.href = split_href[0]+'?'+key+'='+value;
> }else{
> new_para = new_para+ii+"="+para_dict[ii]+"&";
> console.log(split_href[0]+new_para);
> ```

You need to include whitespace around your variables when you join them.

```
//Create New Parameter string
//No parameter present
//var pathname = window.location.href;
```

should have whitespace between the `//` and the content.

---

In `for (ii in para_list)` and `for (ii in delete_key)`, you should use `i` instead of `ii`.

---

I don't know whether this is controllable by you, but `"reportype"` is misspelt.

```
// Add target kay and Value
// Delete key from the dinctionary
```

are misspelt also.

---

Using `para` everywhere is bad practice. Use `parameter` instead, it's much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

It's good to follow the single responsibility principle. The current method does many things that would make sense to extract to smaller helper functions, for example:

- convert query string to dictionary
- concert dictionary to query string
- delete list of keys from dictionary
- ... and so on

What's the point? Next time you need something similar (and most certainly you will), you will be able to reuse the common elements easier.

And yeah, as @Quill said, the names are horrible. Some ideas:

- params instead of para_dict
- index instead of ii
- key_value instead of tmp
- url instead of pathname

Comment: yes, Correct. I will update code tomorrow and again pass for review.Thank You.